# Send an email using VBA on cell change, referencing other columns in row

Tags: excel, vba, email, row

Very new to coding and trying to learn it myself.

I have a large table of data, names, email address etc. Once so much has been completed by an employee, it has to be sent to management for approval. When management have approved/rejected, they use a dropdown to select either 'approved' or 'rejected'.  I want this to automatically create and send an email to the member of staff, including information from other cells within the row.

I have found a code online that kind of works, but only for 1 row. I don't know how to change it to send the details from a different row, if that is 'approved'

The below creates the email as I want it, but doesn't do it on the cell change. Also how do I do it so that if H3 = approved, it sends the information from Row 3, but if Cell C7 = "approved", for it to update with row 7 information?

```
    Option Explicit
Dim Rng As Range
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal mRng As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If mRng.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Set Rng = Intersect(Range("H3:H1000"), mRng)
If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target = ("J3:J1000") And Target.Value = "Approved" Then
Call ExcelToOutlook
End If
End Sub
Sub ExcelToOutlook()
Dim mApp As Object
Dim mMail As Object
Dim mMailBody As String
Set mApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mMail = mApp.CreateItem(0)
mMailBody = "Hi " & Range("B3") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Your expert has been approved." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"See Row " & Range("A3") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Name: " & Range("D3") & (" ") & Range("E3") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Platform: " & Range("F3") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
("Handle: ") & Range("G3") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Notes: " & Range("I3") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"Thanks"
On Error Resume Next
With mMail
        .To = Range("C3")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Your expert has been " & Range("H3")
        .Body = mMailBody
        .Display 'or you can use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set mMail = Nothing
Set mApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

[Basic spreadsheet template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhGKb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  Note you can pass the row directly to the send mail method - no need for a global varaible.

**EDIT**: updated to show how to check multiple columns for different conditions, and split out the "send a mail" function into a separate sub.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only one cell at a time
    
    'check for col J
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J3:J1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Approved" Then   'row is Approved?
            SendApprovedMail Target.EntireRow 'pass row to sendmail sub
        End If
    End If
    
    'check for col H
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H3:H1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then   'row is Approved?
            SendColHYesMail Target.EntireRow 'pass row to sendmail sub
        End If
    End If
    
    
End Sub

'send a mail using info from row `rw`
Sub SendApprovedMail(rw As Range)
    Const NL2 As String = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    Dim mMailBody As String
    
    mMailBody = "Hi " & rw.Columns("B").Value & NL2 & _
        "Your expert has been approved." & NL2 & _
        "See Row " & rw.Columns("A").Value & NL2 & _
        "Name: " & rw.Columns("D").Value & (" ") & Range("E3") & NL2 & _
        "Platform: " & rw.Columns("F").Value & NL2 & _
        ("Handle: ") & rw.Columns("G").Value & NL2 & _
        "Notes: " & rw.Columns("I").Value & NL2 & _
        "Thanks"
        
    SendAMail recip:=rw.Columns("C").Value, CC:="", BCC:="", _
              subject:="Your expert has been " & rw.Columns("H").Value, _
              bodyText:=mMailBody
End Sub

Sub SendColHYesMail(rw As Range)
    Const NL2 As String = vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    Dim mMailBody As String
    
    mMailBody = "Hi " & rw.Columns("B").Value & NL2 & _
        "Some other subject here." & NL2 & _
        "See Row " & rw.Columns("A").Value & NL2 & _
        "Name: " & rw.Columns("D").Value & (" ") & Range("E3") & NL2 & _
        "Platform: " & rw.Columns("F").Value & NL2 & _
        ("Handle: ") & rw.Columns("G").Value & NL2 & _
        "Notes: " & rw.Columns("I").Value & NL2 & _
        "Regards"
        
    SendAMail recip:=rw.Columns("C").Value, CC:="", BCC:="", _
              subject:="Your expert has been " & rw.Columns("H").Value, _
              bodyText:=mMailBody
End Sub


'send an email
Sub SendAMail(recip As String, CC As String, BCC As String, _
              subject As String, bodyText As String)
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .To = recip
        .CC = CC
        .BCC = BCC
        .subject = subject
        .body = bodyText
        .Display 'or you can use .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams, that works exactly as I wanted it to.  I've tried so many ways through google searches, but nothing ever quite worked! 
I'm just learning as I go. 

Assume I can set up a 2nd similar code referencing a different Cell as the Range?

Comment: Yes you can build in additional checks into `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: How would I add that in?  I've used the previous and updated it for my full spreadsheet, and it is working lovely. 
I have a column in 'H' that when it says 'Yes' I want it to send a different email but again referencing cells within the row. 
Sorry to keep asking - I've not done this kind of thing before

Comment: See edits above.

Comment: Hi, I've put this into my spreadsheet and it doesn't generate an email for either column now.   I've tried changing the original code (that is working with 'approved') Target Range to column H, and Target Value to Yes, but then that doesn't work either. 
As soon as I change it back to Column J and Approved, it works again.  Would it make a difference that the 'Yes' is populated with an IF function? 
(=IF(AU3=4,"Yes","Details not complete"))

Thank you for your help so far

Comment: This works for me, but note that if Column H has a formula, then changes in the result of the formula will not trigger a "change" event - you would need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event to handle the "Yes"